# how many routes we can create in routeconfig.cs in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new in asp.net MVC. I want to know that is there  any limit  on total no of routes in routeconfig.cs.

how many routes we can create in routeconfig.cs in asp.net mvc

Comment: It's possible uses many `MapRoute` but important is create the same `defaults:` option in routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit for creating routes as far as I know. As you can make as many controllers you want and it does not limit as each action can represent a unique route.

Comment: does adding more routes like 50-100 in routes.config affects performance

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple routes in RouteConfig.cs like this :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
      "ShoppingManagment",
      "{id}/ShoppingManagment/{action}",
      new { controller="ShoppingManagment", action = "ShoppingManagment", id = UrlParameter.Optional });


    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home",
         action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

}
```

To add multiple routes, kindly check this [ASP.NET Routing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx#adding_routes_to_an_mvc_application).

Make sure the Default route is at the bottom end of your listed route table. Order matters when it comes to ASP.NET MVC Routing tables. The correct ordering is your 'most specific' route to your 'least specific route'. ie the `Default` route is defined at last.

Comment: Is  there  any limit of  total route count in routeconfig.cs?

Comment: I don't think there is any limit. But it may affect performance if you add too many. I am not sure about that. Maybe some experts can comment about that.

Answer (score 0):

there are no limits in creating routes. You can create as many route as you want in your RouteConfig.cs file. But make sure that you provide unique name value to each MapRoute function.